# Identification of German accent in video

Tags: accent

There is a show where one of the girls has a distinct beautiful accent. I would like to know if there is a name for the accent or an area in Germany where people speak this way.

[This is an episode](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3oz4shXD3GA&t=1m48s) of the show where she speaks, the girl has dark brown hair and wears blue.

She speaks at (where I can distinguish her accent) 1m 48s, 3m 59s and 9m 37s.

Comment: God, that show is awful :D As far as I can tell, she doesn't really have an accent. It's just her pronunciation that is quite extreme.

Comment: No accent, except you accept "Hannoverian"

Comment: @Baz hahaha. It's very good for learning Deutsch(the show).

Comment: They all try to speak extr@ clearly.

Comment: However, Sascha's vowels seem to be a bit off.

Comment: This is clearly German for German learners.

Comment: The story plays in Berlin, but noe of the folks speaks the Berlin dialect. Actually, to me it sounds slightly as if none of them is really a *native* speaker (though with *very* good German pronunciation - except of course the "waiter" Sam, who's character is supposed to be non-German) -  This is of course also strange as the actors (except Sam) all have very German names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

She doesn't have an accent or dialect. It's clearly pronounced standard German. No area can be recognized.

Though everyone has an idiolect, and maybe you like hers or just her appearance.